# How can I scheduled an application execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I know that the annotation below will run my code everyday at noon:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12")
```

How can I do to make my code run everyday, three times a day, like:

first time at 08:00 am

second time at 12:00 am

third time at 18:00 pm

?

Comment: This is covered in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Answer (score 1):

This cron will run at 8, 12 and 18 o'clock
`0 8,12,18 * * *`

Use tools like https://bradymholt.github.io/cron-expression-descriptor/ to find your cron expression